# converting string to byte array in c# getting zeros in bytes

Tags: c#

i am using below code to read data in a .key extension file to byte array, i am getting 16 bytes output but all bytes are zeros.

[image]

```
System.IO.StreamReader myFile = new System.IO.StreamReader(Server.MapPath("ELECTRI.KEY"));
    string myString = myFile.ReadLine();
    string str = myString;


     //string str = myString.Substring(0, myString.Length - 2);         

    BitArray bit = new BitArray(str.Length);
    for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
    {
        if (str.Substring(i, 1) == "1")
        {
            bit[i] = true;
        }
        else
        {
            bit[i] = false;
        }
    }
    int numBytes = bit.Count;
    if (bit.Count % 8 != 0) numBytes++;
    keyyy = new byte[numBytes];
```

Comment: Show the content of the file. Does it actually contain the char "1" somewhere?

Comment: because you are not copying bit array into your byte array

Comment: can you specify the code

Answer (score 1):

```
keyyy = new byte[numBytes];
```

This sentence means initializing `keyyy` with `new byte[numBytes]`, so all bytes are zeros. You have to assign each

Comment: Which do you want to get `keyyy` as binary array like `0,1,0,1,...` or byte array like `89,67,221,...`?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code you need to fill the array

```
int numBytes = bit.Count;
if (bit.Count % 8 != 0) numBytes++;
keyyy = new byte[numBytes];
bit.CopyTo(keyyy, 0);
```

Comment: text in the file  string = ȇ˙ļ̉ǇʉđŃöͱǈď̼ŉ

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

```
byte[] keyyy = File.ReadAllBytes("ELECTRI.KEY");
```

I think if I understand your problem correctly now, it is a simple as doing this!

Here is another way you could approach the problem:

```
string str = "1111111100000000";
byte[] keyyy = new byte[str.Length / 8]
    .Select((b, index) => Convert.ToByte(str.Substring(index * 8, 8), 2)).ToArray();
```

This statement splits the string into groups of  8 characters (ignoring remainders) using `Substring`. Each string of 8 characters (i.e. `11111111`) is then converted into a `byte` using `Convert.ToByte`. The [paramter `2`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7xhf79k(v=vs.110).aspx) in `Convert.ToByte` let's the method know it is a base2 binary string.

Comment: text in the file  string = ȇ˙ļ̉ǇʉđŃöͱǈď̼ŉ

Comment: Ah, from your example I thought it was a binary string (1010101) as you check for "1". Do you simply want that string stored in a byte array? Or am I misunderstanding the problem?

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
        byte[] buffer;

        using (StreamReader reader= new StreamReader("PATH HERE")) {
            var input = reader.ReadToEnd();
            buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input);
        }
```

PS: This will read the whole file contents.

Comment: thanks its working fine, but  i am getting 32 byte array, i need only 16 byte array for my encryption. Can you please let me know how to get 16 byte array . Data in the  file which is am reading is " ȇ˙ļ̉ǇʉđŃöͱǈď̼ŉ ".